# can't define function return type properly on typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This is the function that I have implemented for decoding the token with the aid of jsonwebtoken there is problem with return type that I have defined for the function,

```js
import jwt, { decode } from "jsonwebtoken";

export const authentication = (
  token: string
): {
  error: { [message: string]: Error } | null;
  token: { [adminID: string]: string } | null | string;
} => {
  const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token);
  return {
    error: decodedToken
      ? null
      : {
          message: new Error("invalid error"),
        },
    token: decodedToken ? decodedToken : null,
  };
};
```

I'm trying to utilize the function like the code snippet below

```js
  const { token, error } = authentication(context.headers.authorization);
  if (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message.toString());
  }

  const { adminID } = token;
  console.log("this is admin id", adminID);
```

In this part when I'm  going to get adminID by object destructuring type script throws an error in like this

```sh
 Property 'adminID' does not exist on type 'string | { [adminID: string]: string; } | null'.

15   const { adminID } = token;
```

I need to mention that everything is working properly and I can get the `adminID` from `token` but typescript is blaming about this.
any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`{ [adminID: string]: string }` is an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures): it means an object that can be indexed with any string (and the name for the string parameter is `adminID`) and return a string. For an object with an `adminID` property of type `string` you want `{ adminID: string }` instead (and probably `error: { message: Error } | null` as well).

And even better, use a [discriminated (or tagged) union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) instead of two fields one of which must be null. Approximately like this:

```
export const authentication = (
  token: string
): { kind: "error", error: Error } | { kind: "token", adminId: string }
  const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token);
  return decodedToken
      ? { kind: "token", ...decodedToken }
      : { kind: "error", error: new Error("invalid error") };
};
```

Of course code consuming it will need to be changed as well:

```
const authResult = authentication(context.headers.authorization);
if (authResult.kind === "error") {
  throw new Error(authResult.error.toString());
}

const { adminID } = authResult.token;
console.log("this is admin id", adminID);
```

Comment: thanks for your time on this issue, there is another thing going on, `? { kind: "token", ...decodedToken }` typescript is throwing this error. `error TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.

8     ? { kind: "token", ...decodedToken }`

Comment: That depends on what `jwt.decode` return type is. As mentioned, this is approximate. You could also do `{ kind: "token", token: decodedToken }` and adjust other types.

Comment: (I know TypeScript somewhat, but not that library.)

Comment: one the best moves for decoding the token would be passing the `{json: true}` as a useful option for `jwt.decode`